# parsing xml using python into dict

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following xml file and would like to put this information into a dict:

data is the main node which seperates all my entities, so i would want an output like this:

```
'Data1' : {country name: xxx, rank: x, year: x}
'Data2' : {country name: xxx, rank: x, year: x}
'Data3' : {country name: xxx, rank: x, year: x}
```

etc...

also how would i get specific values if i did not want to get everything in my xml within data

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<country name="Liechtenstein">
<rank>1</rank>
<year>2008</year>
<gdppc>141100</gdppc>
<neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
<neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
</data>
<data>
<country name="Sweden">
<rank>1</rank>
<year>2008</year>
<gdppc>141100</gdppc>
<neighbor name="America" direction="E"/>
<neighbor name="Island" direction="W"/>
</country>
</data>
<data>
<country name="Manchester">
<rank>1</rank>
<year>2008</year>
<gdppc>141100</gdppc>
<neighbor name="London" direction="E"/>
<neighbor name="Echo" direction="W"/>
</country>
</data>
```

Comment: Are you experiencing an error? Or stuck at a particular part in the code you've tried to solve this issue? Please show what you have tried and where you're having the issue.

Comment: Is it necessary to specifically create a dictionary with keys with "Data1", etc.?  A list containing dictionary elements may be easier to work with in code once you've parsed the data.

Comment: This Python library is a good starting place:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: I have tried to solve the issue but cant seem to access specific tags with values

Comment: You have to share your current effort (code) with the community.